# how to change the dropdown list of TComboBox?

Tags: delphi, tcombobox

I have a TComboBox and I want to change its dropdown list and replace it with my own control which is (TYazTreeList)

What is the easiest way?

I want to inherit a new control from TComboBox (lets call it TYazComboBox)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`TComboBox` subclasses the Microsoft Windows' [`COMOBOX` window class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775791) from the Windows [Common Control library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169). `COMBOBOX` provides the dropdown, so you should either replace that, or completely write your `TYazComboBox` class (which some 3rd party Delphi control vendors did). Both options are hard.

Comment: but there are FLOSS libs doing this. He can just look how they implement it and do the same.

Comment: @Arioch'The if you know any names, please mention a few. Looking never hurts, although some code I wrote in the past... (:

Comment: I decided it was easier to write my own. I inherited the edit control from a TCustomEdit, added a button, and derived the dropdown from TCustomListBox. You could save some time by starting with TButtonedEdit (or TCustomButtonedEdit) as the edit control which already has a Button.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers i believe  you can find plenty at torry.net, but searchign for combo in my IDE now, maybe http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvCustomHTComboBox
or TJvDBLookupTreeViewCombo or 3 kinds of colorcombo's or FontCombo.

DevExpress also has quite a number of, though learning from them might require clean-room or other redundant settings.